# What scripting language(s) fits this description?

Tags: programming-languages, scripting-language

I like programming language design/implementation and I'd like to contribute to one of the less mature ones. I'm looking for a scripting language that is:

- Embeddable
- Dynamically, strongly typed
- Small & Lightweight (more elaborated later)
- Implemented in C++

With lightweight I mean something like Lua, very small standard library that can be easily extended.

And some (random) design principles that I like:

- The language should have a few very powerful built-in types, like python (int, float, list/array, map/dictionary, set and tuple).
- A function is an object, like in Lua (this makes lambda functions trivial)
- Arguments are passed as tuples that automatically get extracted.

And last and probably also least, I like C-style syntax.

---

If you think about yelling "subjective", "there is no best language" and "not a question", you misread a question. I'm merely asking for a list of scripting languages that match the description above.

Comment: javascript v8 I think is implemented in c++

Comment: @pastjean: __"one of the less mature ones"__ I don't count Javascript as a "less mature" language.

Comment: ohh, as I read i forgot the beginning. IO is a great language. http://www.iolanguage.com/ https://github.com/stevedekorte/io I don't know if it fits your needs (as of maturity, and implemented in C)

Answer (score 0):

[Cython](http://cython.org/)

[Shedskin](http://shed-skin.blogspot.com/)

[Psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/)

These are all scripting languages that are either variants or restricted subsets of the original; python language, that compile to C, C++, or machine code. I believe these should satisfy your req. spec.

Shedskin and psyco also currently have calls for contributions on their main page.

HTH

Comment: You couldn't be more wrong (no offense). Python is not small & lightweight, and it __is__ dynamically and strongly typed (read up on dynamic and strongly typed). And when I want to contribute to a scripting language I don't want to write a compiler. And last and very certainly not least, Python is mature.

Comment: My bad, confused with statically typed; removed incorrect statement